startup twice on ubuntu 22.04 problem
I tried changing the boot order using grub, but my lenovo ideapad 110 laptop still starts up then turns off then on again before entering password page.

This question is similar to: lenovo ideapad 110 starts up twice on Ubuntu 22.04 lts problem. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
